# Placing AsyncTask in Activity or Fragment?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am trying to design an Android app which:

1. grabs JSON data from an HTTP link
2. iterates through the data and forms an `ArrayList` of my `Object`.

Now the HomeActivity extends an ActionBarActivity, which implements TabListener.

It has 2 tabs with a Fragment in each. `Fragment 1` is going to hold a listView from the JSON data. `Fragment 2` is going to show a Google Map with markers based on the same JSON data.

Now, I'm just wondering what is the best approach to use this `AsyncTask`.

Should I place it in the Activity and then use interfaces to pass that ArrayList to both the Fragments?

Or ... how should I do this? Thanks! Some tips on caching would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your fragments are both using the data, it seems reasonable to put your AsyncTask in the activity. If the AsyncTask is a non-static inner class of the Activity, then in your postExecute you can fetch pointers to your fragments from your activity, and then call methods on the fragments to give them the new data (or tell them that you have stored it somewhere -- however you've implemented it).

Comment: Smells like memory leaks.